# Failed to load python Qgis 3.4 add-ins

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I installed Qgis 3.4 Madeira and it worked fine, but now it throws me two errors

The first is the following:

[image: error 1]

The second is:

[image: error 2]

By omitting the two errors that load with several defects, such as: a empty vector box and the python console does not appear.

[image]
[image]